# Is a custom VueJS dist folder location possible?

Tags: deployment, vuejs2

To deploy a VueJS application you run `npm run build`

This creates a dist folder in your dev app structure. Is it possible to change the location of where this dist folder is created.

I create my VueJS apps with the webpack template `vue init webpack app-name`

Comment: Which vue-template are you using?

Comment: vue init webpack app-name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the vue [webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) template you can change the path in the `config/index.js` file:

```js
  build: {
    [...]
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    [...]
  },
```

**Change both lines** to either (for an absolute path):

```js
index: path.resolve('/www/dist/index.html'),
assetsRoot: path.resolve('/www/dist'),
```

or, for a relative one:

```js
index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../deploy/public_html/index.html'),
assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../deploy/public_html'),
```

---

If you're on a Windows environment, you can use the above format or `'C:\\www'` like (just make sure to escape the `\`)

[`path.resolve` docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)